# Objective C How to animate Subview with click in Button

Tags: ios, objective-c, subview

I have a problem :D.

I'm currently using a SplitViewController. At the start I want to hide the TableViewController in the MasterView. So i decided to add a SubView in the Storyboard into the tableView, where a little label will be shown.

So after I make my choice in the DetailView and click the Button I want to hide the subView and want to show the tableView. That all with animations.

So here is my Code:

In the TestTableViewController.m

```
-(void)AnimateView{
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.1];
[UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveLinear];
fixedView.frame=CGRectMake(-500, 0,0,0);
[UIView commitAnimations];
NSLog(@"test");
```

And in the TestDetailViewController.m

```
- (IBAction)attractionButton:(UIButton *)sender
{
    TestTableViewController *testTableViewController = [[TestTableViewController alloc]init];
    [testTableViewController AnimateView];
}
```

I get the NSLog "test" but the Animation is not working. 
fixedView is my Subview and I drag it to the header file so it's an IBOutlet.

Thank you so far.

Comment: You're calling `hideSubview` while your method's name is `AnimateView`.

Comment: Oh yes that was an old name. I edit it :)

Comment: What do you mean by not working?

Comment: There is no Animation. When I call the function in the viewDidLoad Method of the TestTableViewController it works. But if I call it at the button click, nothing happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is, you are not referencing the same master view controller in your details view controller.

You are creating another one in your `IBAction`.

In order to get a hold of your (the "original" one) master view controller, do this in your detail view controller:

Create a ivar:

```
TestTableViewController *masterViewController;
```

And then to reference it:

```
masterViewController = (TestTableViewController*)[[[self.splitViewController.viewControllers lastObject] viewControllers] objectAtIndex:0];
```

For example:

```
- (IBAction)attractionButton:(UIButton *)sender
{
    masterViewController = (TestTableViewController*)[[[self.splitViewController.viewControllers lastObject] viewControllers] objectAtIndex:0];
    [masterViewController AnimateView];
}
```

And finally in your `AnimateView` method, make change to the following:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.1f animations:^
{
     fixedView.frame = CGRectMake(-500, 0, 0, 0);
}
completion:nil];
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: @TdoubleG Then try this: `masterViewController = (TestTableViewController*)[self.splitViewController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:1];`. If it still doesn't work, then we would need to see more code in order to know more about the way you add your views.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It looks like it is working. If I change, for test, the background color, it flashes with the color and than turn back to white. Maybe the state of the Button is the problem?

Comment: @TdoubleG You meant the background color? Show how you do that.

Comment: Ok it works actually. I see the animation. But the subview is not gone. I tried to remove it but without success it looks like there is always a new instance

Comment: @TdoubleG which is not gone? fixedView?

Comment: [UIView animateWithDuration:2 animations:^
    {
        fixedView.frame = CGRectMake(-500, 0, 0, 0);
        fixedView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    }
                     completion:nil];

Comment: yep fixedView. It goes to the right, but the table don't come up.

Comment: @TdoubleG Here your question is about how to animate the fixedView. But you need to mention how you add the master view as well. Was it ever present at all, etc etc, are information we need to diagnose. In general, the tableview doesn't need to "come up" in a master-detail view set up, because they are always there from the beginning.

Comment: Just off the top of my head, add this to completion: `....completion:^(BOOL finished){[fixedView removeFromSuperview];}];`

Comment: I thought of same thing. You know how to position the tableView?

Comment: @TdoubleG if this helps you with the controller and the animation part, accept this answer first and let us have another question about positioning the table view with more relevant code there, I would suggest.

Comment: @TdoubleG in addition, it would help others in the future, too, if they too have problem with positioning table view and read the answer there in a format that is more focused.

Comment: Yep you're right. Here is the post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24304472/objective-c-position-tableview-in-a-splitviewcontroller

Answer (score 1):

So you seem to instantiate a new ViewController and trying to perform this animation straight away:

```
TestTableViewController *testTableViewController = [[TestTableViewController alloc]init];
[testTableViewController AnimateView];
```

The problem is that you don't even present that view controller (its view is not on screen anywhere) so it's normal you don't see any animation.

From my understanding you already have another instance of this view controller presented on screen (am I right?) - so that is the one that you need to use. Pass its pointer to TestDetailViewController in some way (e.g. a property) and then use that object to call your animation method.

PS. I would recommend naming all your methods starting with a lower case letter ;)

Comment: It is a SplitViewController. What do you mean with "its view is not on screen anywhere".

Comment: I mean that you can't create a new VC, but instead you need to use the existing one. If you're using a Split VC your 2 view controller are in the `viewControllers` property of the split view controller (it's an NSArray). You could use that to access the TestTableViewController - the array has 2 objects so check which one of them is 'kindOfClass[TestTableViewController class]' and use that ;)

Answer (score 0):

What you could try is this:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.15f animations:^{
     fixedView.frame=CGRectMake(-500, 0,0,0);
}completion:^(BOOL finished){

}];
```

Are you sure you can call [UIView beginAnimations: ....] without a first argument?

Comment: Yeah it works when I execute the animation in the viewDidLoad Method in the TestTableViewController. I tried also your suggestion but that even doesn't work.